# DataTemplateSelector not getting called

Tags: .net, wpf, telerik

I have a template selector for a telerik control RadTileView. There are no errors, and everything works "fine", but the template selector SelectTemplate() never gets called, and so the program doesn't choose between my 2 data templates. Any ideas? I don't know how to debug this at all. Thank you.

My data template definition and template selector xaml code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="IncidentContentTemplate">code...</DataTemplate>


    <templateselectors:TCardTileViewTemplateSelector x:Key="TCardTemplateSelector" DefaultTCardViewModelTemplate="{StaticResource contentTemplate}"  IncidentTCardViewModelTemplate="{StaticResource IncidentContentTemplate}" />


</UserControl.Resources>
```

My Template selector:

```
public class TCardTileViewTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{

        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {

            if (item is IncidentTCard)
            {
                return this.IncidentTCardViewModelTemplate;
            }
            else
            {
                return this.DefaultTCardViewModelTemplate;
            } 
        }

        public DataTemplate IncidentTCardViewModelTemplate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }


        public DataTemplate DefaultTCardViewModelTemplate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

}
```

My RadTileView:

```
   <telerik:RadTileView Name="MainRadTileView"
                        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource contentTemplate}"
                        IsItemDraggingEnabled="{Binding ElementName=IsItemDraggingEnabledOption,Path=IsChecked}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource headerTemplate}"
                        ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TCardTemplateSelector}"
                        MaximizeMode="{Binding ElementName=MaximizeModeOption,Path=SelectedItem}"
                        PreservePositionWhenMaximized="{Binding ElementName=PreservePositionWhenMaximizedOption,Path=IsChecked}"
                         TileStateChanged="tileView1_TileStateChanged"
                        TileStateChangeTrigger="{Binding ElementName=StateChangeOption, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Remarks section in [ItemTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx):

> Note that this property is ignored if ItemTemplate is set.

Simple solution: do not set the `ItemTemplate` property.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea(though of course it makes sense in hind sight).